# I need to print an input on the same line and not below (which is a new line). Can someone fix my code?

Tags: string, output, newline, line-breaks

I need to have an output like this:

**Enter player name: Mark**

**Mark, choose a column: 2**

and this is my code:

**player = raw_input("Enter player name: ")**

**print player, ", choose a column: "; column = int(input())**

this is the output of my code:

**Enter player name: Mark**

**Mark, choose a column:**

**2**

Can someone help me fix my code?
By the way, I'm using python 2.7.6

Comment: To clarify, your question is specifically about line breaks in Python 2.7.6, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is somehow like that. Instead of printing the input below, i want it to be printed at the same line.

Comment: Use the `{}` button or `Ctrl+K` shortkey to format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`column = int(input(player+ ", choose a column: "))`
I guess you can do it in this way